# Excel vba: adding vlookup result to dictionary doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Scripting.Dictionary` object that a fill with value pairs in a for cycle. The problem is, while `VLookup` finds the value and prints it out in the debug ok.

```
Dim indexes As Object
            Set indexes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            Dim tempYear As Integer
            For tempYear = 2009 To year
    indexes.Add Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("TEXT", _
statsWorkbook.Worksheets("economic").Range(rangeString2), tempYear - 1999, 0), tempYear  'here's the adding


            Debug.Print "inside tempYear cycle"
            Debug.Print "vlookup: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("TEXT", _
statsWorkbook.Worksheets("economic").Range(rangeString2), tempYear - 1999, 0)   'prints out the right value

            Debug.Print indexes(tempYear)  'doesn't print anything
            Next
```

**EDIT:** Now I tried to make the example simpler:

```
Sub testDICT()
    Dim indexes As Object
    Set indexes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    indexes.Add "Lazy boy", "cat"
    indexes.Add "Good boy", "dog"
    indexes.Add "Evil boy", "bear"

    MsgBox (indexes("cat"))
End Sub
```

And I can't get the value either.

Comment: `Debug.Print indexes.Item(tempYear)` - If that doesnt get it working, then try assigning the lookup to a string variable, and then add the string variable to the dictionary instead.

Comment: @braX It didn't change anything. And, to my knowledge, shouldn't have, since `dictionary(key)` is a completely valid syntax.

Comment: What's an example of a result that is not working?

Comment: MsgBox (indexes("Lazy boy"))

Comment: Cat is the value, not the key. You can only retrieve values using the key, as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've swapped the value and the key when you're adding items to your dictionary. See [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/). In your sample code, it should be:

```
Sub testDICT()
    Dim indexes As Object
    Set indexes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    indexes.Add "cat", "Lazy boy"
    indexes.Add "dog", "Good boy"
    indexes.Add "bear", "Evil boy"

    MsgBox (indexes("cat"))
End Sub
```

Or in your real code:

```
Dim indexes As Object
            Set indexes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            Dim tempYear As Integer
            For tempYear = 2009 To Year
    indexes.Add tempYear, Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("TEXT", _
statsWorkbook.Worksheets("economic").Range(rangeString2), tempYear - 1999, 0)  'here's the adding


            Debug.Print "inside tempYear cycle"
            Debug.Print "vlookup: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("TEXT", _
statsWorkbook.Worksheets("economic").Range(rangeString2), tempYear - 1999, 0)   'prints out the right value

            Debug.Print indexes(tempYear)  'doesn't print anything
            Next
```

Let me know if that solves your problem.